# Using GPT partition type with SQL Server in production?

Tags: sql-server, storage, disk-structures

We are currently using MBR partition type with our SQL Server in production, but as our data volume increases, we are facing issues with our data drives getting full. We can't extend them because they are MBR, which means we have to either stop SQL Server and move some files or add a new file to the database.

We are considering switching to GPT partition type, but we are not sure if there are any potential problems that we need to be aware of before making the switch. Has anyone else used GPT partition type with SQL Server in production? If so, have you experienced any issues?

We would appreciate any insights or experiences you can share with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone else used GPT partition type with SQL Server in production?

Yes.

> If so, have you experienced any issues?

No.

---

Not much more I can really say about that, especially while not being an infrastructure expert (you can try for general information about the differencs on [ServerFault](https://www.ServerFault.com)). But I've been in the same situation. Ran out of disk space on MBR disks. Migrated the database to GPT. Had to restart the SQL Server service in order to move the database data and log files.